On the conditions for Ex. 5.14, Atiyah-Macdonald

Let $A$ be an integrally closed domain, $K$ its field of fractions and $L$ a finite normal separable extension of $K$. Let $G$ be the Galois group of $L$ over $K$ and let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $L$. Show that $\sigma(B)=B$ for all $\sigma\in G$, and that $A=B^G$.

My question is about the second part: $A = B^G$. Why does $B$ need to be the integral closure of $A$ in $L$ for that to apply? Isn't it enough for $B$ to be integral over $A$ and contained in $L$?
Wouldn't it still be the case that $B^G = B \cap L^G = B \cap K = A$? (the last equality follows from B being integral over A and A an integrally closed domain)

I know we could define $B^G$ even when $B$ is not closed under $G$, but did they?

@AnneBauval I don't think so. $A^G$ is defined in Ex. 5.12 by let $A^G$ denote the subring of $G$-invariants, that is of all $x \in A$ such that $\sigma(x)=x$  for all $\sigma \in G$

Well if they want to write $B^G=\dots$ but only defined $B^G$ when $G$ acts on $B$, that is a good reason for requiring $B$ to be the whole integral closure and not just a subset.

yeah, i guess that even if I define $B^G = B \cap L^G$ then I don't think I can prove for instance that $B$ is integral over $B^G$
